# Switch view between two tables

Tags: postgresql

I have two tables a and b. 
I have a view which on table a 
 I need to use same view on table b it should unlink from table a and tomorrow again same view should point to table a and unlink table b. How should I use one view between two tables

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: How should I use one view between two tables

Answer (score 0):

First, create a view of table a:

```
CREATE VIEW theView AS
SELECT column1, column2
FROM a
```

Then, to update a view to show a different table (in this case, table b), use the CREATE OR REPLACE statement:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW theView AS
SELECT column1, column2
FROM b
```

Comment: This is correct.  Just be aware that you'll need an exclusive lock on "theView" while this happens.  If there are no other transactions blocking, the lock will be extremely short.